# Is it really necessary to put lock.unlock() in a finally block?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

Is it really necessary to `lock.unlock()` in a `finally` block? The following is a common idiom

```java
try {
    lock.lock();
    // some code
} catch (Exception e) {
    // exception handling
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

however, here's what [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) has to say:

> If execution of the body is ever completed, either normally **or abruptly** *[presumably, e.g. due to an exception]*, an **unlock action is automatically performed** on that same monitor.

Is it really necessary to put `lock.unlock()` in a `finally` block then? Or did I misunderstand the specification?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. The section of the JLS you linked is talking about `synchronized`, not `java.util.concurrent.locks`.

Comment: FYI, it's more idiomatic to `lock()` before `try`. That way it doesn't try to unlock if it should fail to lock.

Comment: @Slaw but `java.util.concurrent` classes simply wrap (decorate) the basic `synchronized`, `wait()`, etc., don't they? If something is true for those, it must also be true for `java.util.concurrent`, mustn't it?

Comment: No, it mustn't. There's a reason these are referred to as explicit locks.

Comment: @JoreJoh No, `Lock` doesn't _decorate_ synchronized.

Comment: Re, "...wrap...the basic `synchronized`..." `Lock` is [more powerful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressive_power_(computer_science)) than `synchronized` blocks. That's why Locks were added. They let you do things that you _cannot_ do with `synchronized` and `o.wait()` and `o.notify()`. (e.g., you can lock a `Lock` in one function, and then unlock it in a different function.) If Lock implementations and synchronized blocks both happen to "wrap" the same underlying mechanism (they almost certainly do) then that's an implementation detail, not part of the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The section of the *Java Language Specification* (JLS) you linked is talking about `synchronized`. Specifically, it's saying that if you have the following:

```java
synchronized (someObj) {
    // guarded code
}
```

Then when that `synchronized` block exits for any reason, including an exception being thrown from within the block, it's guaranteed the implicit monitor of `someObj` will be unlocked.

The [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) API is a separate thing, and is not covered by the JLS (though obviously relies on the Java Memory Model (JMM) as defined by the JLS). That means you have to read the Javadoc of the API to know how its defined to work.

Here's an excerpt from the package documentation:

> Interfaces and classes providing a framework for locking and waiting for conditions **that is distinct from built-in synchronization and monitors** *[emphasis added]*. The framework permits much greater flexibility in the use of locks and conditions, at the expense of more awkward syntax.

And here's an excerpt from the documentation of [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> With this increased flexibility comes additional responsibility. **The absence of block-structured locking removes the automatic release of locks that occurs with `synchronized` methods and statements** *[emphasis added]*. In most cases, the following idiom should be used:
>
> ```java
> Lock l = ...;
> l.lock();
> try {
>   // access the resource protected by this lock
> } finally {
>   l.unlock();
> }
> ```

As you can see, it's necessary to unlock the lock in a `finally` block<sup>1</sup>. Also note that the call to `lock()` is done *before* the `try` block. This prevents trying to unlock the lock in the case where the call to `lock()` failed for whatever reason.

---

<sup>1. A major reason why the `java.util.concurrent.locks` API was created is to provide more flexibility than the block-structure of `synchronized`. You may have a more complex scenario where you need to call `unlock()` far removed from the call to `lock()` or at some unspecified moment in the future, meaning calling `unlock()` in a `finally` block may not be the correct approach. But as noted by the documentation, that means you, the developer, have more responsibility. It's up to *you* to guarantee `unlock()` is called when appropriate.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! But how is it safer to include `lock()` before `try`? How can a thread proceed if it can't acquire the lock? Doesn't it simply block?

Comment: In normal operation, yes, the thread will block if it can't acquire the lock immediately. But [`Lock#lock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock()) is defined to let implementations throw unchecked exceptions, meaning the call can fail without acquiring the lock (even if that may be unlikely). There's also [`Lock#lockInterruptibly()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lockInterruptibly()), which you may want to use, and which can throw an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: I just checked the source code for `ReentrantLock` and saw that `lock()` doesn't in fact throw anything

Comment: @JoreJoh not sure which source you are looking at, but in jdk 11 the ReentrantLock uses an internal Sync which at the very least can throw an Error if the maximum lock count is exceeded.  additionally, if the lock attempt is queued, there is memory allocation, which can also throw an error.  regardless, the point is that `lock()` _is allowed_ to throw an exception, and therefore the best practice is to put it outside of the try/finally block.

Comment: @JoreJoh As noted, what the implementation does is beside the point. The important thing is the contract of `Lock#lock()` _allows_ unchecked exceptions to be thrown. And typically, you'll be "programming to the interface" anyway. Plus, [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) specifically states: "_This lock supports a maximum of `2147483647` recursive locks by the same thread. Attempts to exceed this limit result in `Error` throws from locking methods_".

Comment: All that ignores other ubiquitously possible errors. In short, you want to avoid hiding those errors behind an `IllegalMonitorStateException` because you called `unlock()` in a `finally` block without actually holding the lock.

Comment: @Slaw I acknowledge that the part about "hiding those errors behind an `IllegalMonitorStateException`" is a good argument